# order of SQL Server query execution using MS Excel

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba

I have an MS Excel workbook that has 4 tabs that each use a SQL statement to pull data from SQL Server - I am curious if there is a way to define in what order these should be executed when I hit refresh all?  I am assuming it involves VBA but not sure.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's just as simple as this.

```
Sub RefreshAll()

ActiveWorkbook.Connections("CONNECTION_NAME1").Refresh
ActiveWorkbook.Connections("CONNECTION_NAME2").Refresh
ActiveWorkbook.Connections("CONNECTION_NAME3").Refresh
ActiveWorkbook.Connections("CONNECTION_NAME4").Refresh

End Sub
```